# Dependency Issues: Google Play

Tags: android, google-play-services

You will find my build.gradle for my working project below. I am trying to add Google Play Services functionality to my existing app and so I am adding the following to my dependencies:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0'
```

The issue is once I rebuild I get many errors:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]
/Users/Fred/Documents/Undergraduate #2/Winter 2017/COMP361/Ongoing/CatAndroid/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values-ldltr-v21/values-ldltr-v21.xml
Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner.Underlined'.
Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner.Underlined'.
/Users/Fred/Documents/Undergraduate #2/Winter 2017/COMP361/Ongoing/CatAndroid/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values-v21/values-v21.xml
Error:(13) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Inverse'.
Error:(15) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large.Inverse'.
Error:(21) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium.Inverse'.
Error:(28) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small.Inverse'.
Error:(212) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar'.
Error:(214) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar.Horizontal'.
Error:(222) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material'.
Error:(232) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Light'.
Error:(254) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.DialogWhenLarge.NoActionBar'.
Error:(172) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.AutoCompleteTextView'.
Error:(185) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.EditText'.
Error:(6) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material'.
Error:(4) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body1'.
Error:(5) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body2'.
Error:(7) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Caption'.
Error:(8) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display1'.
Error:(9) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display2'.
Error:(10) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display3'.
Error:(11) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display4'.
Error:(12) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Headline'.
Error:(14) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large'.
Error:(16) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
Error:(18) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
Error:(20) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium'.
Error:(22) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Menu'.
Error:(23) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Subtitle'.
Error:(25) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Title'.
Error:(27) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small'.
Error:(29) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Subhead'.
Error:(30) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Title'.
Error:(31) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
Error:(33) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle.Inverse'.
Error:(35) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
Error:(37) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse'.
Error:(39) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle'.
Error:(41) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Title'.
Error:(43) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button'.
Error:(49) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
Error:(51) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
Error:(53) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
Error:(54) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem'.
Error:(55) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
Error:(57) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
Error:(102, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
Error:(106, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorButtonNormal'.
Error:(104, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
Error:(105, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
Error:(103, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
Error:(100, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
Error:(101, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
Error:(109, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowElevation'.
Error:(149, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
Error:(153, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorButtonNormal'.
Error:(151, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
Error:(152, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
Error:(150, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
Error:(147, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
Error:(148, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
Error:(156, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowElevation'.
Error:(159, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowElevation'.
Error:(161) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabText'.
Error:(163) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabView'.
Error:(165) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'.
Error:(167) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.CloseMode'.
Error:(170) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.Overflow'.
Error:(175) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button'.
Error:(176) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Borderless'.
Error:(177) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Borderless.Colored'.
Error:(180) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Small'.
Error:(181) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ButtonBar'.
Error:(182) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.CompoundButton.CheckBox'.
Error:(183) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.CompoundButton.RadioButton'.
Error:(184) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.DropDownItem.Spinner'.
Error:(188) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ImageButton'.
Error:(189) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
Error:(191) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
Error:(193) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabView'.
Error:(195) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.PopupMenu'.
Error:(199, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:overlapAnchor'.
Error:(201) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListPopupWindow'.
Error:(203) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListView'.
Error:(204) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListView.DropDown'.
Error:(206) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.PopupMenu'.
Error:(210, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:overlapAnchor'.
Error:(216) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.RatingBar'.
Error:(217) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.SeekBar'.
Error:(218) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner'.
Error:(219) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.TextView.SpinnerItem'.
Error:(220) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Toolbar.Button.Navigation'.
Error:(246, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
Error:(250, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorButtonNormal'.
Error:(248, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
Error:(249, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
Error:(247, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
Error:(244, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
Error:(245, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
Error:(13) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Inverse'.
Error:(15) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large.Inverse'.
Error:(21) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium.Inverse'.
Error:(28) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small.Inverse'.
Error:(212) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar'.
Error:(214) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar.Horizontal'.
Error:(222) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material'.
Error:(232) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Light'.
Error:(254) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.DialogWhenLarge.NoActionBar'.
Error:(172) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.AutoCompleteTextView'.
Error:(185) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.EditText'.
Error:(6) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material'.
Error:(4) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body1'.
Error:(5) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body2'.
Error:(7) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Caption'.
Error:(8) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display1'.
Error:(9) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display2'.
Error:(10) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display3'.
Error:(11) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display4'.
Error:(12) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Headline'.
Error:(14) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large'.
Error:(16) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
Error:(18) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
Error:(20) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium'.
Error:(22) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Menu'.
Error:(23) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Subtitle'.
Error:(25) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Title'.
Error:(27) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small'.
Error:(29) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Subhead'.
Error:(30) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Title'.
Error:(31) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
Error:(33) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle.Inverse'.
Error:(35) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
Error:(37) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse'.
Error:(39) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle'.
Error:(41) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Title'.
Error:(43) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button'.
Error:(49) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
Error:(51) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
Error:(53) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
Error:(54) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem'.
Error:(55) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
Error:(57) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
Error:(102, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
Error:(106, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorButtonNormal'.
Error:(104, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
Error:(105, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
Error:(103, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
Error:(100, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
Error:(101, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
Error:(109, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowElevation'.
Error:(149, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
Error:(153, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorButtonNormal'.
Error:(151, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
Error:(152, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
Error:(150, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
Error:(147, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
Error:(148, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
Error:(156, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowElevation'.
Error:(159, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowElevation'.
Error:(161) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabText'.
Error:(163) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabView'.
Error:(165) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'.
Error:(167) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.CloseMode'.
Error:(170) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.Overflow'.
Error:(175) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button'.
Error:(176) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Borderless'.
Error:(177) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Borderless.Colored'.
Error:(180) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Small'.
Error:(181) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ButtonBar'.
Error:(182) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.CompoundButton.CheckBox'.
Error:(183) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.CompoundButton.RadioButton'.
Error:(184) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.DropDownItem.Spinner'.
Error:(188) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ImageButton'.
Error:(189) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
Error:(191) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
Error:(193) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabView'.
Error:(195) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.PopupMenu'.
Error:(199, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:overlapAnchor'.
Error:(201) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListPopupWindow'.
Error:(203) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListView'.
Error:(204) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListView.DropDown'.
Error:(206) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.PopupMenu'.
Error:(210, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:overlapAnchor'.
Error:(216) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.RatingBar'.
Error:(217) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.SeekBar'.
Error:(218) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner'.
Error:(219) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.TextView.SpinnerItem'.
Error:(220) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Toolbar.Button.Navigation'.
Error:(246, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
Error:(250, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorButtonNormal'.
Error:(248, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
Error:(249, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
Error:(247, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
Error:(244, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
Error:(245, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
/Users/Fred/Documents/Undergraduate #2/Winter 2017/COMP361/Ongoing/CatAndroid/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values-v23/values-v23.xml
Error:(37) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner.Underlined'.
Error:(33) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Borderless.Colored'.
Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Menu'.
Error:(4) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
Error:(34) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
Error:(35) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.RatingBar.Indicator'.
Error:(36) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.RatingBar.Small'.
Error:(37) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner.Underlined'.
Error:(33) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Borderless.Colored'.
Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Menu'.
Error:(4) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
Error:(34) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
Error:(35) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.RatingBar.Indicator'.
Error:(36) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.RatingBar.Small'.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 3.408 secs
Information:211 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

I know that adding the dependency is what causes the issue, but I have no idea how to correct this.

Here is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.settlers.hd"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
compileSdkVersion 19
.... support-v4:19.1.0'
```

That is really old and not compatible with either your build tools or the latest version of Google Play Services.

For example, see the error has `values-v21`, but you aren't compiling with API 21.

You also are missing `appcompat-design` for material design styles.

You can `compile` with the latest SDK (25) and still `target` any older version.

Note: You should [select only the Google services you really need](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#split).